# LongRunningRecognizeResponse should implement com.google.protobuf.Message

Tags: android, asynchronous, google-api, speech-recognition, speech

While using Google Speech API in an android project, I ran into a problem when implementing an asynchronous request to send audio file.
When I create the variable `OperationFuture <LongRunningRecognizeResponse> response` - an error occurs in the generic type - “Make ‘LongRunningRecognizeResponse’ implement ‘com.google.protobuf.Message’.

I considered an example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech.

There is Streaming Speech Recognition. Doing so does not help.

**Edited:**
If I implement a "Message" interface, it results to an error:[image]

[image]

**Edited**: if make this

```
OperationFuture<com.google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse,
                com.google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata>
```

[image]
then it will also...
Maybe I can kind of generate `.proto` files from scratch?

Comment: Sure, see editing question.

Comment: are u getting a clean compile?   have you tried build with --info  and or --debug

Comment: no, please, describe by details what u mean

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/index.html) the type of longRunningRecognizeAsync is

```
 OperationFuture<com.google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse,
  com.google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata>
```

Not

```
OperationFuture<com.google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse>
```